# Determining the actual filenames of the tables in PostgreSQL at file system level

Tags: storage, filenames, postgresql-9.1

I'm using the following code to determine the disk size of each table in my database in postgresql:

```
 SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('"my_schema"."my_table"'));
```

I imagine that I should find the actual filenames of each table to get the exact disk size. Does anybody know how to determine the actual filenames at file system level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select t.relname, current_setting('data_directory')||'/'||pg_relation_filepath(t.oid)
from pg_class t
  join pg_namespace ns on ns.oid = t.relnamespace
where relkind = 'r'
and ns.nspname = 'public';
```

I'm not 100% this will show the correct path if multiple tablespaces are involved.

Comment: That will identify the first segment of the main fork of the relation. It will not include other forks (like the visibility map), TOAST data, or indexes -- just the first heap file. When that file reaches 1MB, additional files will be created with `.1`, `.2`, etc. suffixes.

Comment: @kgrittn I have files with as big as 450MB. Are you sure that Postgres creates a new file every 1 **MB**?

Comment: Oops. I hate it when I do that. It is indeed 1 **GB** per segment. The point holds, though, that to assess the size of a table, one needs to look at a lot more than the one file indicated by this answer.

Comment: @kgrittn: Ah, thanks. Is there a solution that would display **all** files for tables bigger than 1GB?

Comment: If the original file name is `16789`, the rest of the heap would be in `16789.*` and other forks would be in `16789_*`.  Any data too large to be stored in-line will be spread around the TOAST relation identified by `reltoastrelid`, which would need to be evaluated for space just like the original table, and added in. Both the base table and the TOAST table can have indexes, which you can find in `pg_index` based `indrelid` matching the `oid` of the base or TOAST table. (`indexrelid` points back to a pg_class row for the index.) Now you know why the pg_*_size() functions where written.